# Reading xml with partial whitespace

Tags: xml, whitespace, xmltextreader

I've a xml file with partial whitespace;

```
<file>
  <document>
     <data>1</data>
     <data>2</data>
     <data>3</data>
  </document><document>      //whitespace missing
     <data>1</data>
     <data>2</data>
     <data>3</data>
  </document>
</file>
```

When i use XmlTextReader to read the xml file and use the following code to find an element;

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFile);

while (reader.Read())
 {
  {
   if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
```

it doesn't find the second element `<document>` (caused by the reader position)
How can i change my code to read all elements.
As a workaround i now write a temporary file replacing `><` with `>\n<`

Answer (score 0):

If no-one else is answering:
My guess is you're reading the xml inside the loop, maybe with ReadOuterXml().
Whitespace between elements shouldn't matter.